# Problem with robot_upstart

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-kinetic, rosrun, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install robot_upstart for my package

```
serge@media:~/NetBeansProjects/ROS_beginner_tutorials/ros_ws$ rosrun robot_upstart install beginner_tutrorials/launch/m1.launch
```

But I get the error

```
Unable to locate path launch/m1.launch in package beginner_tutrorials. Installation aborted.
```

I already entered the command

```
source ./devel/setup.bash
```

And am definitely sure that it it works, because

```
rosrun beginner_tutorials talker
```

works properly. And if I do not enter source command I can't run the talker, so the source is added

Also when I enter

```
rospack find beginner_tutorials
```

the package can be found.

So what can be a cause of the problem?
And maybe I understand something wrong about robot_upstart. Does it creates a new launch file or can only write/overwrite data in existing launchfile or maybe it require a ready launchfile?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268161/problem-with-robot_upstart/) by [Sergey Kravchenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27657/sergey-kravchenko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> serge@media:~/NetBeansProjects/ROS_beginner_tutorials/ros_ws$ rosrun robot_upstart install beginner_tutrorials/launch/m1.launch
> ```

If that is an actual copy-paste, then the problem is most likely the typo in the package name: `beginner_tutrorials`.

The correct package name (and the one you use in the "I'm definitely sure that it works" bit) is `beginner_tutorials`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sergey Kravchenko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27657/sergey-kravchenko/) on 2017-08-08**:
sorry, my bad:)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-09**:
No problem. Glad you got it to work.